# I am unable to get graph from R

Tags: r, graph

So I made a correlation graph on R. Now I want to save it as png on my laptop with a higher width, height and resolution but whenever I run the command and then do `dev.off()` a png file is saved to my working directory but its empty

I run this code it runs properly

```r
png(file = "Corr.Fluconazole.HMF.png", width = 3000, height = 3000, 
           res=500)
dev.off()
```

on the console I get this

```r
> jpeg(file = "Corr.Fluconazole.HMF.jpg", width = 3000, height = 3000, 
       res=500)
> dev.off()
RStudioGD 
        2
```

An empty file saves and I cannot see my graph

Comment: You didn't do any plotting command ... so this is as expected!

Comment: I did the plotting command. I have edited my comment and you can see the command.

Comment: I see first `png( ...`   and then `dev.off()`, I see no plotting